# Select table for insert/update statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I wanted to throw this out there for some ideas.  I'm writing a program to generate insert/update statements, and I want the table that I insert/update to come from the results of a query.  So something like (please forgive the syntax):

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT TBL_NAME FROM MYTABLES WHERE A=B) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

I have to do this in Oracle, but I'm not too familiar with their declare statements or syntax.  I'm guessing the best way to go about it is to declare a variable that is the result of the SELECT, but then can I use that variable as the table name for the INSERT?

I also want to keep the code in SQL.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  An `insert` statement doesn't fetch any rows, it inserts rows.

Comment: He wants to insert the values into a table whose name he determines from the subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may want to look into [Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm), you may find your answer (or at least a decent starting path) there.

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL is necessary for this.  The query to determine the table name would need to be executed first as a normal inline query, then the insert statement would need to be built as a string, incorporating the table name obtained from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' || TBL_NAME || ' VALUES (''A'', ''B'', ''C'');' cmd
FROM MYTABLES WHERE A=B
;
```

Run this select, then run the results of the select (which is insert statements). 
Don't forget to "commit".

Regards,
Roger
All views are mine ...